# How can i add a new codec in ffmpeg

Tags: android, performance, ffmpeg, video-player

I am creating a project in android where I have to increase the performance of the android video player. I need to install some supportive codec with ffmpeg to make my video player better while playing HD video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The codecs that are enabled in FFMPEG are set during the build process.

Take a look at the following post. It describes how to exclude codecs in the build process and is not Android specific, but it is the same configuration process to remove and include codecs:

[Compile FFMpeg without most codecs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24849129/compile-ffmpeg-without-most-codecs)

As you are building for Android you are likely using a ready made android project such as:

https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg

If this is the case it has a file `configure_ffmpeg.sh` that will let you set which codecs to include and exclude in the build process.

Be sure that you are not violating FFMPEG licensing in the way you include and use FFMPEG in your app.

https://www.ffmpeg.org/legal.html

Comment: Hi @brentm I am using appunite android project, can you help me that how can i add a new codec in appunite

Comment: Information about codec support and configuring codec support can be found here: https://www.ffmpeg.org/general.html. I haven't used AppUnite's build, but take a look in the '/FFmpegLibrary/jni/build_android.sh' file they set '--disable-everything' then manually enable support for each encoder and decoder.

Comment: Ya I did that  but it doesn't  speed up my player