# How to configure ffmpeg just to play RTSP videos

Tags: android, ffmpeg, apk, rtsp

I have successfully compiled ffmpeg for android and everything is working fine.

I have made specific build for each architecture and even with that it's **9.7-9.9MB** in `debug version`.

My sole target is just to play `RTSP video` with `authentication`.

What should be the command line options for this while configuring?

> my current script looks like this

```
./configure \
        --prefix=$prefix \
        --pkg-config=/usr/bin/pkg-config \
        --enable-shared \
        --disable-static \
        --disable-doc \
        --disable-ffmpeg \
        --disable-ffplay \
        --disable-ffprobe \
        --disable-avdevice \
        --disable-symver \
        --cross-prefix=$toolchain/bin/$crossPrefix \
        --target-os=android \
        --arch=arm \
        --enable-cross-compile \
        --sysroot=$sysroot \
        --enable-network \
        --extra-cflags="$mArchFlag" \
        --extra-ldflags="$extraLDFlags"
```

Comment: Probably to remove all the encoding parts. You also should decide which video and audio decoders to use, almost any video/audio format can be transferred through rtsp, but usually it's just something like AVC(h.264).

Comment: BTW, which ffmpeg version do you use? 9.7-9.9MB seems to be rather small for the configuration

Comment: I have downloaded the latest release from github 3.9.4 probably.

Comment: @AntonMalyshev how to remove codecs and formats which I dont need while configuring?

Comment: Not too bad for the new version :) posted my exact suggestion as an answer

Answer (score 2):

You can compile with `--disable-encoders --disable-muxers` flags, also you can exclude specific decoders which are surely don't needed, for example, `--disable-decoder=mp3`... That should reduce the size much.

Also you can check the full list of flags here: [Compile FFMpeg without most codecs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24849129/compile-ffmpeg-without-most-codecs), most probably you don't need some protocols and parsers too, although from my past experience that does not reduce size too much.