# Custom Build of FFMPEG only for screenshots

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg

I have a disk space issues while using static FFMPEG build in my lambda. So can i use Customized FFMPEG build only to take screenshot for my Videos(All Formats Ex: mp4, mov, ...) to JPG. Any suggestions or anyone having reference to get the custom build only for this purpose.

Comment: Answer depends on the exact formats you need to support. MP4 & MOV container formats support many video formats (H.264, HEVC, ProRes, etc). Which do you need to support? Is JPG the only output format you need? Do you need to perform any scaling or other filtering?

Answer (score 0):

You can [compile](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide) ffmpeg yourself.

[This answer and its comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24849194) go into enabling/disabling encoders and decoders. You'll want to remove every video encoder (because you'll be saving jpg/png) and (re)enable any video formats you want to support.

If you don't want to compile yourself, a pre-compiled static build may be smaller. It saves you from having to install multiple packages from a package manager - all you need is the single binary.

A [static build](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html) (linked lower on the page) with all default features is about ~75mb.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Am not good at playing with these binary files. Can you help me to get the custom build for only to do screenshots of any video formats?

Comment: The static build I linked will fit in Lambda's 50 compressed / 250mb uncompressed file size limit. Just use that if you don't want to compile yourself.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But am getting Disk Size Error because already lambda filled with around 210MB only 40MB space left so would like to create a custom build only with screenshot functionality.